# Календарь, меняющий месяца и годы

Tags: javascript, функции, дата, календарь

По заданию нужно сделать календарь и стилизовать его с помощью js. У меня не выходит перекрасить выходные в тёмно-серый. Использую селекторы для этого, а они не работают, хотя, если выводить в консоль выбранные дни, то массив дней правильный.
Так же кнопка < должна выводить прошлый месяц этого же года, а << - прошлый год, но месяц тот же.

```js
//getDate - номер дня
//getDay - день недели
function calendar () {
    const monthNames = ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь",
        "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"
    ];
    let mon = prompt('Какой сейчас месяц по счёту?');
    //в js отсчет начинается с 0, а не 1
    month = mon - 1;
    year = prompt('Какой сейчас год?');
    let calendaricForYou = new Date( year, month );
    let elem = document.getElementById('calendaric');
    let table = '<table id = tableOfDays><tr><td class = RedCat><button id = YearBefore><<</button></td><td class = RedCat><button id = MonthBefore><' +
        '</button></td><td colspan=3 id = forMonth class = RedCat></td>' +
        '<td class = RedCat><button id = MonthAfter>></button></td><td class = RedCat><button id = YearAfter>>>' +
        '</button></td></tr><tr id = hiddenDates><th>пн</th><th>вт</th><th>ср</th><th>чт</th><th>пт</th><th>сб</th><th>вс</th></tr><tr>';

    //заполнение ячейками в зависимости от того, с какого дня недели начинается месяц
    for (let i = 0; i < getDay(calendaricForYou); i++) {
        table += '<td></td>';
    }

    //заполнение ячеек цифрами
    while(calendaricForYou.getMonth() ===  month){
        table += '<td>'+calendaricForYou.getDate()+'</td>';
        //если доходим до воскресения, то нужен перевод строки
        if(calendaricForYou.getDay() % 7 === 0){
            table += '</tr><tr>';
        }
        calendaricForYou.setDate(calendaricForYou.getDate() + 1);
    }

    //добавляем ячейки, если заканчивется не в воскресенье
    if(getDay(calendaricForYou) !== 0 ){
        for(let i = calendaricForYou.getDay(); i <= 7; i++){
            table += '<td></td>';
        }
    }

    table += '</tr></table>';
    //добавляем код в body
    elem.innerHTML = table;

    //добавляем свойства
    let hiddenTR = document.getElementById('hiddenDates');
    hiddenTR.style.display = 'none';
    let tableOfDays = document.getElementById('tableOfDays');
    tableOfDays.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';
    tableOfDays.style.margin = '0 auto';
    let otherTD = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (let i = 0; i<otherTD.length; i++){
        let other_TD = otherTD[i];
        other_TD.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        other_TD.style.borderColor = '#dddddd';
        other_TD.style.borderWidth = '2px';
        other_TD.style.padding = '3px';
        other_TD.style.textAlign = 'center';
        other_TD.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
        other_TD.style.width = '30px';
        other_TD.style.height = '30px';
        for(let j = 0; j>getDay(calendaricForYou); j++){
            other_TD.style.backgroundColor = 'white!important';

        }
    }
    //не работает!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    let holidayTD = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(n+6)");
    for (let i = 0; i<holidayTD.length; i++) {
        let holiday_TD = holidayTD[i];
        holiday_TD.style.backgroundColor = '#4257!important';
    }
    let forMonth = document.getElementById('forMonth');
    forMonth.style.color = 'white';
    forMonth.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
    forMonth.innerHTML = monthNames[month];

    let button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for (let i = 0; i<button.length; i++) {
        let button_ = button[i];
        button_.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        button_.style.borderRadius = '10px';
        button_.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        button_.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        button_.style.outline = 'none';
    }
    let redTD = document.getElementsByClassName('RedCat');
    for (let i = 0; i<redTD.length; i++) {
        let red_TD = redTD[i];
        red_TD.style.backgroundColor = '#e33';
    }
    let monthBefore = document.getElementById('MonthBefore');
    monthBefore.onclick = function(){
        month = mon - 2;
    }

}

//получить номера дней недели
function getDay(date) {
    let day = date.getDay();
    if (day === 0) day = 7;
    return day - 1;
}

calendar();
```

```html
<div id ='calendaric'></div>
```

Comment: Отредактируйте Ваше исходное сообщение, чтоб код можно было выполнить `(Ctrl + M)`

Comment: Если я убираю !important у меня рисует holiday_TD.style.backgroundColor = '#4257';

Answer (score 0):

Просто не нужно писать CSS стили напрямую в код. Добавьте к проекту CSS таблицы и манипулируйте классами. Например для всех ячеек определите класс .day { background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); } а для выходных дней подставляйте к ячейке еще один класс. Например .Feier {background-color: rgb(181, 178, 178) !important;} Таким образом стиль цвета класса day будет переназначен.